# Ubuntu 18 get timeout on all my SMB mounts, but not Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Fedora 25 or Windows 7 and 10

Tags: samba

I have a couple of SMB mounts on some different Linux machines.
Most of them are hosted on a ClearOS 6 or 7 machines and I have never had problems mounting these smb mounts on any earlier Ubuntu version, Fedora or Windows before, but Ubuntu 18.04 always gets a timeout when transferring big lots of data.

Ubuntu 16.04 worked like a charm for years.
I do have one Ubuntu 18.04 machine that works great with the SMB, but that was upgraded from 16.04, the clean installed Ubuntu 18.04 machines does get a timeout.

Just checked and the Ubuntu 18 machine that have no problems with my SMB servers runs an older kernel than the ones that are clean installed.
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-58-generic x86_64)
vs.
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-29-generic x86_64)
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-25-generic x86_64)

I know they aren't fully updated, but my SMB issues have been present all the time on a clean installed Ubuntu 18.04.

Does anyone have any ideas of why my clean installed Ubuntu 18.04 machines timeout compared to Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04 upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04, Fedora or Windows.

Different tweaks I have tried on the samba servers under [global] to no avail.

```
socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_KEEPALIVE  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_THROUGHPUT  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_THROUGHPUT SO_KEEPALIVE  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=16384 SO_SNDBUF=16384  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=16384 SO_SNDBUF=16384  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_THROUGHPUT SO_RCVBUF=16384 SO_SNDBUF=16384  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_THROUGHPUT SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=16384 SO_SNDBUF=16384  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_THROUGHPUT SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536  

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_THROUGHPUT SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
```

Does anyone have any ideas why the timeout only happens on these
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-29-generic x86_64)
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-25-generic x86_64)
machines?

Edit:
From the log

```
[2019/09/23 15:22:54.310475,  1] smbd/process.c:457(receive_smb_talloc)
  receive_smb_raw_talloc failed for client 192.168.10.70 read error = NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET.
[2019/09/23 15:22:54.370419,  1] smbd/service.c:1378(close_cnum)
  buntu (192.168.10.70) closed connection to service
```

And i have this under [global] too

```
client min protocol = SMB1
client max protocol = SMB3
```

I know SMB1 isnt safe anymore but this is on a local LAN only and used in support for older software and Phones at the moment.

Comment: Are there any clues in the Samba logs of the Samba host? If there are any relevant errors, please [edit] your question to add them. I'm making the assumption that you can access these, obviously that may not be the case.

Comment: fyi: the fedora (25) you mention is well EOL (as is 26, 27, & 28 are EOL) which is I suspect a big clue; ie. I suspect your issue is with changes because of wannacry, ie. security that was improved to protect windows machines - 16.04 & f25 were pre-wannacry; later fedora & Ubuntu 18.04 were post-wannacry.  (the centos/clearos releases you give are also old)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really think about that, but Ubuntu 18 connects fine just timeout when transferring big chunks of data. But I will try to upgrade one of my ClearOS machines and see how it goes.